# jQuery ui slider to resize all elements within a div

Tags: jquery, resize, uislider

really struggling with this ?? I am very new to Jquery and trying to stumble my way through it...

here is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/VUY4p/

I cant figure out how to get it to work, I need all the divs to scale with the bottle image and also to be centred, so when the main slider is all the way to the right the view is of just the label area with the text at around 300px wide and then when moving slider to the left the entire bottle is visible and everything else shrinks with it, including the text in the same proportions as the close up view.

i hope this makes sense and I hope someone can take a look and see whats wrong?

Also something strange happens to the text when the font is changed as the bottle image is increased?? it jumps to the left??

Comment: Are you looking for somethng like this http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/VUY4p/3/?

Comment: thanks,  not really what I was after, I need the bottle to scale within the container like drawdesign just created (perfect!) but I also need the text to scale with it and still be able to change the font size in proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not help you, but I thought it might be better to redo the image area. Perhaps some of it will help you.  I think it is too much code to post in the answer.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/ggC8s/6/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your zoom in for you, but I don't quite understand what you want the text to do. you want it to fit into the bottles label?

http://jsfiddle.net/NtMhF/1/

Comment: I need the text to basically be over where the "jasmine duncans" text is and scale in proportion to the bottle, I will eventually be recreating all the text on the label with similar input fields and need them all to be able to scale so I can edit the text and see a full length image and a close up image,